# Recognize the type of a value saved in the Database as a String

Tags: c#

I have a problem that I'm not able to solve.

I'm getting a value from a Database. This value in the database is saved as a `nvarchar`.

I need to understand the type of the value.

For example:

- 12.12.2012 -> DateTime
- 15:00 -> Time
- 67.45 -> Double

For undesrtand the type I use the `TryParse` method.

Example for understand if it is a DateTime I execute this code:

```
DateTime valueConverted;

if(DateTime.TryParse(input.ToString(), out valueConverted))
{
   // IS DATETIME
}
```

The problem is that if the value got from the DataBase is:

- 0900
- 009000

I would like the recognize it as a String. The problem is that the conversion to a double has success and then the value is converted to a double with value = 900.

How can I recognize that the value like 0900, 00060 are not double but `String`?

Comment: Create a column called 'Type' .....

Comment: I can't add new column to the table.

Comment: Can you change type of column?

Comment: If the DB type is nvarchar, that means the value is a string. If it is not a string, that means the model is messy. You may (if you can) really change the datatype of the column to store the expected type.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest would probably be to match against `^0[0-9]+$`.

Realize though this is a non-trivial problem and you're bound to find edge cases you didn't expect. I recommend changing the data model if you are at all able, and either store different types in different columns or have a separate column that denotes the data type stored. Storing everything as a string is generally a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 0):

This seems massively oversimplified, but based on your description it will do the trick:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) &&
    input[0] == '0' &&
    input.All(c => char.IsDigit(c)))
{
    // We have a string.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can used regex-match

create all type of datatype format string and match with regex.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match

Answer (score 0):

```
if (input.StartsWith("0"))
{
    // string
}
else
{
    // double
    var number = double.Parse(input);
}
```